# ajax post to laravel can't redirect,form submit can redirect

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, redirect

First of all, I am a Chinese student. I will try my best to explain my question, but my English is not very good. So sorry.
  In my login web, I will use `ajax post` data`(id,passwd...)` to a route. After all confirm, if the data was right, login web will redirect to another web route. But the controller function can not redirect. Like:

```
return redirect('wx/setdev');
//not work in controller function ,but work in route function
```

If I submit a form to controller, controller can redirect to the web route but `ajax` can't.

```
$.post("{{route('cfmlogin')}}",{
   _token : "{{csrf_token()}}",
   user : $('#num').val(),
   passwd : $('#passwd').val()
});
```

I don't know why! Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: return redirect()->to() might not work. But you can write redirect on success function in ajax that can work in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning an redirect to the ajax response, you have to return the url and let the ajax callback function redirect to the url.

So you need to change

```
return redirect('wx/setdev');
```

to

```
return url('wx/setdev');
```

and in your jQuery ajax [post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), pass an third parameter for the success callback function to redirect

```
$.post("{{route('cfmlogin')}}", {
    _token : "{{csrf_token()}}",
    user : $('#num').val(),
    passwd : $('#passwd').val()
}, function (data) {
    window.location = data;
});
```

Comment: Like you said . Is AJAX can't cope http-response？If `return redirect('wx/setdev')` laravel will send the html file to ajax.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you do `return redirect('wx/setdev')` it would send an http 302 response to the ajax and it wouldn't send the html file

Comment: `$.post(url,{},function(data){alert(data)});` That will print html code which I redirect html file.

Comment: Are you returning a `url` or are you returning a `view` ?

Comment: I have a `wx/setdev` route ,if visit this route,will return a view.

Comment: So just return the url to the route to the ajax